# How to create job id for Vertex AI manually or how to access job id in custom container?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

Is there the possibility to manually specify the "Custom job ID" when starting a custom job on Vertex AI?

If not, is it possible to somehow access the automatically created job id from inside the custom container?

Comment: According to the [google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/samples/aiplatform-get-custom-job-sample) we cannot create a custom job id but we can specify the job name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a late reply, but I'll put my answer to this question for future readers.

I was porting the `custom jobs` in the GCP `AI platform` to `Vertex AI`. Previously, AI platform was able to specify the `job id` when submitting the custom job like the below example. However, in vertex AI, the custom job id cannot be specified.

##### AI platform vs. Vertex AI (bash)

```bash
# AI platform
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training ${JOB_ID} \
    --project=${PROJECT_ID} \
    --module-name trainer.task --package-path ./trainer \
    --region us-central1 --python-version 3.7 --runtime-version 2.11 \
    -- \        
    --param1=${param1} \
    --param2=${param2} \
    --param3=${param3}

# Vertex AI
gcloud ai custom-jobs create \
    --display-name=${DISPLAY_NAME} \  # cannot specify JOB_ID
    --region us-central1 \
    --project=${PROJECT_ID} \
    --python-package-uris='gs://[MODULE_PATH]/[MODULE_NAME]-0.1.tar.gz' \
    --worker-pool-spec=machine-type=e2-standard-4,replica-count=1,executor-image-uri='us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/training/tf-cpu.2-7:latest',python-module=trainer.task \
    --args=param1=${param1} \
    --args=param2=${param2} \
    --args=param3=${param3}
```

One possible solution to retrieve the `job_id` is to retrieve the job information with `display_name` filters.

Below is the python3 example of using [`ListCustomJobsRequest()`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.types.ListCustomJobsRequest) and [`JobServiceClient()`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.services.job_service.JobServiceClient).

##### Retrieve Vertex AI `Job ID` with filtering `display_name` tag (Python)

```python
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1  # extension

client = aiplatform_v1.JobServiceClient(
    credentials=credentials,
    client_options={"api_endpoint": "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com"}
)
request = aiplatform_v1.ListCustomJobsRequest(
    parent=f"projects/{PROJECT_ID}/locations/{LOCATION_ID}",
    filter="display_name=[DISPLAY_NAME]",
)
page_result = client.list_custom_jobs(request=request)


for response in page_result:
    print(response)
    print(response.name)  # → "projects/[PROJECT_ID]/locations/[LOCATION_ID]/customJobs/[JOB_ID]"
    print(response.name.split('/')[5])
    print(response.state)  # → JOB_STATE_SUCCEEDED/JOB_STATE_PENDING
```

##### References

- [`gcloud ai custom-jobs create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai/custom-jobs/create)
- [`gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/jobs/submit/training)
- [`list_custom_jobs()`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/1.19.0/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.services.job_service.JobServiceClient#google_cloud_aiplatform_v1_services_job_service_JobServiceClient_list_custom_jobs)
- [`ListCustomJobsRequest()`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/1.19.0/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.types.ListCustomJobsRequest)