# How to retrieve inputs from a Vertex AI custom job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, configuration, config, google-cloud-vertex-ai, custom-training

I created a custom job on Google Cloud Platform Vertex AI based on a Python distribution with some configuration inputs. For example:

[image]

The list of these inputs are available in the *Training* menu in a JSON format:

```
{
  "workerPoolSpecs": [
    {
      "machineSpec": {
        "machineType": "n1-standard-4"
      },
      "replicaCount": "1",
      "diskSpec": {
        "bootDiskType": "pd-standard",
        "bootDiskSizeGb": 100
      },
      "pythonPackageSpec": {
        "executorImageUri": "europe-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/training/sklearn-cpu.1-0:latest",
        "packageUris": [
          "gs://my_bucket_for_vertexai/my_package_directory/trainer-0.1.tar.gz"
        ],
        "pythonModule": "trainer.task"
      }
    }
  ],
  "baseOutputDirectory": {
    "outputUriPrefix": "gs://my_bucket_for_vertexai/my_output_directory/"
  }
}
```

How can my job automatically retrieve these parameters without their value being written in the Python code ?

Comment: I think you can use the combination of environment variables and command-line arguments to pass these configuration parameters to the custom job without their value being written in the Python code. Within the python code, use library to retrieve environment variable and command-line arguments. 

Let sya for example, use the "os" library to access environment variables and the "argparse" library to parse command-line arguments.

Comment: Next step would be in the Vertex AI custom job configuration, set environment variables with the values you want to pass to your Python code. And then submit the custom job to Vertex AI. And then in the python code use "argparse" to parse command-line arguments. This will allow the custom job to retrieve configuration parameters dynamically at runtime. and you don't need to hard code it.

Comment: I configure the custom job with the default interface of the Vertex AI Training and run it by clicking on "START TRAINING", no command-line. Do you think there are solutions without running command-line ?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the JSON you show with `aiplatform.CustomJob.get(job_id)`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780270/12527375) shows how you can get the job ID. The only thing is, I am not sure if these resources are created *before* the container is run so that it can access them..